# Wait for WinForms async method to return before closing

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I have a WinForms app that looks up some data from tables and sends out said data to an external API via HTTP. In the app I display a data grid that lists the rows that contain the data sent via the API.

I would like to have the application exit itself after it is done sending the data via the HTTP API. How do I wait for the asynchronous method `GetEventData` to finish executing before having the program shut itself down?

```
public Main()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  GetEventData();

  // Exit the app
  Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

The method that calls the API is below (entire method not shown just `await` portion)

```
private async void GetEventData()
{ 
  \\ Get data from database code before here

  ClientDataObject client = new ClientDataObject();
  apiResult = await client.SendDataVia API(); 

  // Update the grid with list of rows that were sent to API
  UpdateGridView();
}
```

Currently, the application starts and then exists right away. I believe this is because the `GetEventData` method is not blocking the rest of the code. I am using `async` and `await` so the GUI remains responsive (able to display state of data in database) while waiting for the API calls to complete

Comment: You're calling Exit inside the constructor? Why not just put Exit inside GetEventData?

Comment: I certainly could put it there. Why would it be better inside the `GetEventData` method?

Comment: @mikez The idea is to separate the business logic from the presentation.  The method to get the data shouldn't be manipulating the UI, it should just be getting the data.

Comment: Because it would provide the sequencing you seem to be asking for. Although it seems rather odd to get some data, display it, then immediately exit.

Comment: inside the updategridview method do you set the datasource on the gridview? if so you can for example subscribe to the DataBindingComplete event on the datagridview and exit there.

Comment: Looking at the answers and solution there has been confusion about what this code you posted is about. Maybe you can post more code to clear up the confusion? Is this a main method or did you name your Form Main and this is it's constructor? If it is, what keeps you from invoking `.Close()` on it when appropriate?

Comment: @Servy It's already got logic and presentation mixed together. I don't see how my suggestion significantly affects that concern.

Comment: @nvoigt There is no ambiguity in the question.  That is not the valid syntax for a method as there is no return type specified.  It would need to have a `void` to be the entry point of the application.  Regardless, he specifically mentioned in the question that this is a winform application, not a console application.

Comment: @mikez True, I would argue that the existing UI updates should be pulled out of the business logic, rather than even more UI manipulation put in.

Comment: @Servy I don't even see why the UI updates are there. The application is going to exit immediately after completing the update. No one is going to see it.

Comment: The user requested a display to see what was taking place while the app was sending it's data. The app is intended to be started periodically from SQL Agent and then shut down. Hence the shutdown code. Originally I designed it with a timer loop, but requirements changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async` method shouldn't be `void`.  You should only have an `async void` method when the method is a handler for an event.  It should return a `Task`.  You can then exit the application in response to that task being completed:

```
private async Task GetEventData()
{ 
    //...
}

public Main()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  GetEventData()
      .ContinueWith(t => Environment.Exit(-1));
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming `t` is just a construct of a lambda expression?

Comment: @webworm It is the name given to the parameter of the anonymous method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.Wait()` method of `Task` to wait for it to complete.

```
public Main()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  GetEventData().Wait();

  // Exit the app
  Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: @Servy indeed, blocking is what he is asking for. I don't see any UI in that thread that would suffer.

Comment: He specifically said that he's doing the work asynchronously to not freeze the UI.  This is doing exactly that.  He most certainly does *not* want to be blocking the UI thread, and said so explicitly.

Comment: @Servy maybe the UI will be posted later. I'm more than happy to react to changing requirements, but right now there is no UI and his requirement is to block the thread so the `main` program does not end.

Comment: What are you talking about?  Did you even read the question?  This is a winform application.  There already is a UI.  He specifically said that he is using asynchrony here to not freeze the UI.  He doesn't want to block the UI thead.  He has said nothing at all about wanting to intentionally block the UI thread.  He explicitly said *the exact opposite*.  Perhaps you need to go re-read the question.  He doesn't need to post anything about what his UI is; it is irrelevant to the question.  That it exists is all we need to know.  All you need to know is to not block the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy Well, it seems I was confused by the fact that if you are right, he named his Form Main. Maybe he did. I'll let this stand so he can decide for himself what he actually meant.

Comment: My apologies if I should have explained better but @Servy is correct. This is the `Main()` method from the Main.cs class from my WinForms app.